# How do I resize an image in Python using scipy.misc.imresize so that it matches the size of another specified image

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, image-resizing

For my code here, there are two images known as "org_content" and "output":

```
elif cp_mode == 'lum2':
            output = args.output_lum2
            org_content = args.org_content
            org_content = imread(org_content).astype(float)/256
            output = imread(output).astype(float)/256

            org_content = rgb2luv(org_content)
            org_content[:,:,0] = output.mean(2)
            output = luv2rgb(org_content)
            output[output<0] = 0
            output[output>1]=1
            imsave(output_a_name, output)
```

I receive an error if there is a size difference between the two images:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lum_transfer.py", line 123, in <module>
    org_content[:,:,0] = output.mean(2)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (666,1000) into shape (1024,1536)
```

I need to resize "org_content" so that it matches the length and width of "output". This is because preserving the size/quality of "output" is more important than preserving the size/quality of "org_content".

The rgb2luv and luv2rgb functions are not important to the size difference issue.

I tried using this to fix the problem, but it still resulted in the same error message:

```
org_content = scipy.misc.imresize(output, org_content.shape)
```

I have also tried:

```
org_content = img_as_float(scipy.misc.imresize(output, org_content.shape))
```

So what am I doing wrong here, and how do I solve this issue?

I have the following libraries in my script:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
from skimage import io,transform,img_as_float
from skimage.io import imread,imsave
from numpy import eye
```

---

My full script can be found here: https://gist.github.com/ProGamerGov/2e7a0fe7a5ef6e117dc0be81df243331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I used:

```
org_content = skimage.transform.resize(org_content, output.shape)
```

Which required me to add:

```
import skimage
```

To my script as well.